# docker-compose for jakartaee restful jpa web application not working

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, jakarta-ee, payara

I am struggling for a few days to write a docker-compose file for a simple jakartaEE/JavaEE restful JPA web application. DB is PostgreSQL and the application server is payara. This application inserts few entries to the DB and returns the collection in each rest call response. When I deploy the same application in the locally installed payara and Postgres, it is working fine. But it is failing with docker-compose with the error:

```
An error occurred during deployment: Class 
       com.docker.java.petstore.service.PetstoreService has unsupported major or 
      minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java 
      Runtime Environment version 1.8.0_222. Please see the server.log for more details.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5dtp.jpg

I tried deploying the war file from the payara admin console but failed with the same error.

The relevant code is shown here in the gist: 
        https://gist.github.com/JohnyzHub/cf8e9560b8640dbfd27dc4bb98d5991c

The environment used:

```
        java 11
        JakartaEE 8
        Payara appserver
        postgresql
```

Using `glassfish-resource.xml` file for dynamically creating the connection pool and data source.

***The error looks strange, I am using java 11 but the error is about a specific java 8 version. I am not getting any clue what could be wrong here.***

When I deployed the similar java 11 web application without JPA layer with a same docker file, it is working fine on docker.

Let me know if additional details are needed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [Payara Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/payara/server-full) on Dockerhub are using Java 8 inside. This clashes with your Java 11 compiled source code and does not work.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/payara/docker-payaraserver-full/issues/99) for this on GitHub, but unfortunately, now answer for months.

As a work-around either pick another application server (e.g. Open Liberty Universal Base Docker images have tags for the [latest Java versions](https://hub.docker.com/r/openliberty/open-liberty)) or build your own Docker image from e.g. an OpenJDK 11 base image.

To figure out how to create your own Docker image, I would suggest to have a look at [Adam Bien's Docklands repository](https://github.com/AdamBien/docklands), which contains multiple examples.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs,Philip Riecks. May I know why the same application barring jpa layer is working fine with java 11? There is no code specifically using any java 11 syntax in that application.

Comment: To answer this, please update the question and provide more Information/Code about what you JPA layer acutally is

Comment: I provided all the code in the gist.github link mentioned in the problem description. Did you get chance to take a look of that?

Comment: If I create the docker image by just changing the java version to 1.8 in the pom file, everything working fine as expected. This proves that there is no code in this war file that need java version 11. This make me believe that the problems is something different.

Comment: I assume that when you change to 1.8 in the pom file, your source gets compile with the Java 8 compiler. Then it can run on Java 8 VM. But if you compile with Java 11 compiler, it can't run on Java 8 VM, it requires Java 11+ VM. You would need a docker image with Java 11. Payara has plans to provide Java 11 based docker images soon. Until then, you need to use a community provided docker image or build your own.

Answer (score 1):

The error of your server says you compiled the classes in a higher version (JDK11) than its currently using (JDK8) in the docker image.

Check the used Java Runtime on the Application Server Docker image.
Then either compile the petstore using that JDK8 version of the server, or upgrade the docker container image to use a higher JDK than the one used to compile.